# Pass custom values from parentOrderController to order-payment.tpl

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.6

I had modified some part of reorder in parentOrderController, created a variable. Now I want to pass that variable into the order-payment.tpl so that I can check a condition with that. Can someone please help me?

### ParentOrderContoller.php(Added Part)

```
if (Tools::isSubmit('submitPay') && $id_order = (int)Tools::getValue('id_order')) {

        //To check the order is in print ready state
        $order = new Order((int)$id_order);
        $current_order_state = $order->getCurrentOrderState();                      
        $current_order_state_id = $current_order_state->id;
        //ends here
        //d($current_order_state_id);


        // $this->context->cookie->current_order_state_id = $current_order_state->id;

        $oldCart = new Cart(Order::getCartIdStatic($id_order, $this->context->customer->id));            
        $duplication = $oldCart->duplicate();

        if (!$duplication || !Validate::isLoadedObject($duplication['cart'])) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Sorry. We cannot renew your order.');
        } elseif (!$duplication['success']) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Some items are no longer available, and we are unable to renew your order.');
        } else {
            $this->context->cookie->id_cart = $duplication['cart']->id;

            $context = $this->context;
            $context->cart = $duplication['cart'];
            CartRule::autoAddToCart($context);
            $this->context->cookie->write();
            d(Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE'));
            if (Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') == 1) {
                Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-opc');
            }               
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order');
        } 
    }
```

I want $current_order_state_id to be passed to order-payment.tpl. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
      'current_order_state_id' => $current_order_state_id
));
```

Just a side note. If the variable is not always set, in your template check using the:

```
{if isset($current_order_state_id)}
      code
{/if}
```

Comment: When I debug I had  found that whenever I assign smarty variable inside the "if" condition the variable is not coming in template, if I assign smarty variable outside the if condition, the constant value assigned by me is coming.

Comment: you need to check what part is failling in the condition. The Tools::isSubmit('submitPay') or (int)Tools::getValue('id_order'). And in what funtion of the ParentOrderController do you use this?

Comment: I checked separately also and changed my condition like if (Tools::isSubmit('submitPay')){ this .Still not coming

Comment: (Tools::isSubmit('submitPay') is a action from a button i want to pass the value inside this condition

Comment: I don't quite understand what you said. Doesn't the if evaluate to true and the code inside is executed?

Comment: when i print or die inside the if statement it is coming . The smarty assign is the only one is not occurring inside it.

Comment: In what function and where do you use your code? There are some redirection at the end. It would prevent the assign as it would be a new request.

Comment: i had create a button in order history page. when the button is clicked the action- submit pay is called and it is entered into the if condition